# javascript mandatory data error in screenleap api

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, screensharing

i have a json encoded data in a variable named $json, it looks like-

```
    string(1243) "{"screenShareCode":"882919360",
    "appletHtml":"",
    "presenterParams":"aUsEN5gjxX/3NMrlIEGpk0=",
    "viewerUrl":"http://api.screenleap.com/v2/viewer/882919360?accountid=mynet",
    "origin":"API"}"
    }
```

i need to pass this json data into javascript function, please see below

```
    script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.screenleap.com/js/screenleap.js">/script>
    script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
    var screenShareData = '?php echo $json;?>';
        screenleap.startSharing('DEFAULT', screenShareData);
      };
    /script>
```

when i am trying to run this code it is giving me an error saying **"missing mandatory screen share data"**. 
**How to solve this error?**

```
i am following "https://www.screenleap.com/api/presenter"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you implement it *based on the documentation*

https://www.screenleap.com/api/presenter

```
<?php

// Config
$authtoken = '';
$accountid = '';

// 1. Make CURL Request
$url = 'https://api.screenleap.com/v2/screen-shares';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('authtoken:<authtoken>'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'accountid=<accountid>');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($data, true);

?>

<!-- 2. Launch the Presenter App -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.screenleap.com/js/screenleap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        screenleap.startSharing('DEFAULT', JSON.parse('<?php echo $json; ?>'));
    };
</script>
```

If this doesn't work, you got to report it to screenleap.

Comment: it is giving an error saying "Expected }".  $json is already in json formated.

Comment: i've updated my answer, try that. I thought screenleap requires a JSON object, but it looks like it takes the JSON string.

Comment: giving javascript error: "missing mandatory screen share data"

Comment: i've updated my answer with complete code for the implementation. try it.

Comment: hi, i tried so, but it is giving me an javascript error saying "Unterminated string constant".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `$json` is a string, you need to pass in a json object.  Try the following:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var screenShareData = '?php echo $json;?>';
        screenleap.startSharing('DEFAULT', JSON.parse(screenShareData));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to actually parse the JSON if you want to access the values. Otherwise, just pass the response data right into the startSharing function, like this:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://api.screenleap.com/v2/screen-shares';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('authtoken:<your authtoken>'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'accountid=<your accountid>');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($data, true);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.screenleap.com/js/screenleap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        screenleap.startSharing('DEFAULT', <?php echo $data; ?>);
    };
</script>
```

If you just insert your own accountid and authtoken (without leading spaces), that should work for you.